# Create new local user without access to my files

Tags: windows

I'd like to create a new local user for school on my pc without access to my current files. My current account has a lot of clutter and files from video games and such. When I make a new basic account, I still have access to everything that was installed on my main user profile.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you create a *new user*, then that new user does  not have access to your files *unless you create the new user with administrative rights*. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-local-user-or-administrator-account-in-windows-10-20de74e0-ac7f-3502-a866-32915af2a34d

Comment: The following article talking about how to add a non-administrator account on windows 10, you can have a look:https://help.familyzone.com/support/solutions/articles/5000759701-how-to-add-a-non-administrator-account-on-windows-10    By default your local user account is set as a limited account, meaning it cannot install applications or make administrative changes to the machine.

Comment: Okay, I have made a new user as a standard profile. However, when I go to the new user I am still able to see applications such as Steam, Discord, etc. I pretty much just want a new account with a blank slate.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't files, those are programs.

The other user will not be able to see things contained within C:\users\yourusername, which is what is meant when you use the words "I don't want them to see my files".

The other user will be able to see and use any programs installed to C:\Program Files\ (or it's 32bit analog), which is what you're seeing and what is, apparently, confusing you.

To prevent someone from seeing programs, you'll have to install only programs that support being installed only to the user profile.

To make this more complex, programs installed for all users may still be dependent on user data limited to each individual profile, which is also by design. So, your Discord accounts and settings will only be accessible when you are logged on, so the program running for all users, accesses the application account data stored only in your profile, and for the other user it will not show your chats or account, but will be able to be used by the other user of the computer to connect to their own chats.

Steam may store its game files in a folder that all users on the computer can see, but once again, your account information is only accessible when you are logged in to the computer.

So, you've already solved your problem: You have created an account that cannot access your files.